# How can I specify a multipart file upload with params

Tags: java, swagger, micronaut

I'm trying to document an API method that will receive a file and two parameters as int. Using swagger editor I was able to describe what I want, but couldn't replicate that using annotations.

[image: what I want]

This is what I draw on swagger editor

```
requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                flow:
                  type: integer
                environment:
                  type: integer
                file:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
        required: true
```

If I use `consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` I get the params. And if I use `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` I get the file to upload.

[image: failed attemp 1]
[image: failed attemp 2]

```java
@Operation(summary = "Unpack Files",
            description = "Receives a packed zip or gzip file with xml files inside or receives xml files",
            security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "apiKey"),
            responses = {
                    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "Created"),
                    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Something Went Wrong"),
                    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Unauthorized"),
                    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "503", description = "Service Unavailable")
            },
            requestBody = @RequestBody(
                content = @Content(
                    mediaType = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA,
                    schema = @Schema(implementation = Document.class, format = "binary"),
                    encoding = @Encoding(
                            name = "file",
                            contentType = "application/xml, application/zip, application/gzip"
                    )
                ),
                required = true
            )
    )
    @Post(value = "/unpack", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Single<HttpResponse<String>> upload(StreamingFileUpload file, int flow, int environment) throws IOException {
        return Single.just(new Document(file.getFilename(), environment, flow))
            .flatMap(DocumentValidation::validateDocumentExtension)
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
                log.error("Validation exception: {}", throwable.getMessage());
                exception = throwable.getMessage();
            })
            .doOnSuccess(doc -> {
                log.info("File saved successfuly");
                File tempFile = File.createTempFile(file.getFilename(), "temp");
                file.transferTo(tempFile);
            })
            .map(success -> {
                if (exception != null || !exception.equals("")) {
                    return HttpResponse.<String>status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("Uploaded");
                } else {
                    return HttpResponse.<String>status(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).body(exception);
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE` ?

Comment: I'm using micronaut and this constant it's not available. But as for as I check this is just another way to say "multipart/form-data" right?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like missing `@QueryValue`

From documentation [6.4 Simple Request Binding](https://docs.micronaut.io/1.2.0.RC1/guide/index.html#binding):

> Bindings from a request URI variable or request parameter | @QueryValue String myParam

From documentation [6.19 File Uploads](https://docs.micronaut.io/1.2.0.RC1/guide/index.html#uploads):

> The method is set to consume MULTIPART_FORM_DATA
>
> The method parameters match form attribute names. In this case the file will match for example an
>
> The StreamingFileUpload.transferTo(java.lang.String) method is used to transfer the file to the server.

`Kotlin` simple:

```
@Controller
class SomeController {

    @Post(value = "/", consumes = [MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA])
    fun upload(file: StreamingFileUpload,
               @QueryValue flow: Int,
               @QueryValue environment: Int): Single<HttpResponse<String>> {
        val tempFile = File.createTempFile(file.filename, "temp")
        return Single.fromPublisher(file.transferTo(tempFile))
                .map { success ->
                    if (success) {
                        HttpResponse.ok("Uploaded");
                    } else {
                        HttpResponse.status<String>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
                                .body("Upload Failed")
                    }
                }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi tsarenkotxt, I tried as you suggest, but still, have the same problem.